# Django Object doesn't save

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-views

I am running a script to save objects in my database (in Django)

The script that is giving problems is running in a for loop where basically all values differ each iteration, I want to save each iteration's values as an object in my database.

(this script is located in views.py and is triggered each time the page is refreshed):

```
ses = Sessions(db=row['DB_ID'],
                                   sessionId=session['sessionId'],
                                   dataSource=session['dataSource'],
                                   deviceCategory=session['deviceCategory'],
                                   platform=session['platform'],
                                   sesTime=activit,
                                   hostname=host)

ses.save()
```

my model:

```
 class Sessions(models.Model):
    db = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    sessionId = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dataSource = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    deviceCategory = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sesTime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    hostName = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="U")
```

Where the values that vary are always in the following format (this is if I print the values before trying to save:

```
activit = 2020-05-13T07:45:21.933659Z
host = company.customer.location
```

I don't know where my mistake is, because I don't get any errors, but the object won't save. I have migrated several times.

Please help

Comment: can you show forms.py?

Comment: i don't have a forms.py, maybe another name? Or I don't know where it is located

Comment: sorry forms.py was irrelevant, where do you get vars `activit` and `host`

Comment: I am looping through dictionaries, so both are values from the dict

Comment: did you see some error in console when running?

Comment: nope, its just not saving.. the only errors I get is because of the data not saving

Answer (score 0):

Wow, let this be a lesson to all.. My case was wrong, I had both hostname and hostName, when I only needed hostName